# How to set layout with XML in View for BaseAdapter getView() method

Tags: java, android

The following Java code (from https://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-adapters-adapterviews/) is from getView(), a method implementation from a Android Adapter class, and it builds a View in Java to populate items on a List. I get how it works, but the same page says it can be built using an XML file, which makes sense to me, but I'm unable to find any examples. I understand how to use XML resource files to set Activity layout using setContentView(). But how would I invoke an XML resource file to build the View in the getView() method?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(context);
        view.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        view.addView(new CheckBox(context));
        TextView nameTextView = new TextView(context);
        nameTextView.setText(courses.get(position).getName());
        nameTextView.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
        view.addView(nameTextView);
        TextView parTextView = new TextView(context);
        parTextView.setText(Integer.toString(courses.get(position).getPar()));
        view.addView(parTextView);
        return view;
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

item_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder; // use holder
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_test, parent, false);
        holder = new Holder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.name.setText("name");
    return convertView;
}

public class Holder {
    private TextView name;

    public Holder(View view) {
        name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    }
}
```